# Php Zip manipulation

Tags: php, zip

I have a zip file.
I need a simple way to read the name of the files from the zip and read the contents of one of the files.

Can this be done directly in memory without saving,opening and reading the files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to open the archive and then can iterate over the files by index:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open('archive.zip'))
{
     for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++)
     {  
          echo 'Filename: ' . $zip->getNameIndex($i) . '<br />';
     }
}
else
{
     echo 'Error reading .zip!';
}
```

To read the content of a single file you can use [ZipArchive::getStream($name)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-getstream.php).

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open("archive.zip");
$fstream = $zip->getStream("index.txt");
if(!$fp) exit("failed\n");

while (!feof($fp)) {
    $contents .= fread($fp, 2);
}
```

Another way to directly do it is using the zip:// stream wrapper:

```
$file = fopen('zip://' . dirname(__FILE__) . '/test.zip#test', 'r');
...
```

Comment: For read-only access you'll need http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-getstream.php otherwise you'll have to extract it first

Comment: Sorry, somehow misunderstood your question - fixed the answer.

Comment: This is perfect.One more thing. Can I read the zip from a stream if it's provided by a web service without saving the file ?

Comment: See the third example on this page http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php for another zip:// stream wrapper option